# Regular Expressions - Finding missing currency symbols when price might contain forward slash

Tags: regex, grep

So I thought this would be easy, but I can't wrap my head around it. 
I need to GREP the following list and only find the strings where there is a missing euro symbol.

```
x80/90
x90€
x80/95
x80/95€
x80/90
x90
```

Then I need to add the missing euro symbol.
I really thought I could manage such a simple example, but it has me stumped.

Thanks all.

Comment: Is it possible to have the symbol at anywhere except the middle. Something like `90€x` is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *find* lines with a missing euro symbol you can use `grep` with inverted matching (parameter -v)

```
grep -v '€' < ./your/file
```

To *replace* them you can use `sed` like this:

```
sed -e '/€/!s/.\+/\0€/' < ./your/file
```

Here...

- `/€/` tries to find the euro symbol as a precondition.
- `!s/.\+/\0€/` carries out substitution only on those lines where the precondition was not met.
- `.\+` requires at least one character so that empty lines will not get an euro symbol.
- If that distinction is not necessary for your case, `!s/$/€/` would work as well.

Comment: I may be over-cautious, but may be this logic will not work if the symbol is present by mistake anywhere but not at the last

Comment: I think it would work no matter where the euro symbol is on the line - that's what `/€/` does, after all.

Comment: I meant the `grep` logic.

Comment: That's the same - it finds all lines where there's no euro symbol. Hm... Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness, just wanted to convey, if there is a line `90€x` in the file, should it be considered having the symbol or not? because it is not at the end. Agree it could be an invalid case, but just to be sure.

Comment: Ahhh now I know what you mean. Yeah, that's for the OP to decide. It would be an easy fix that I will leave as an exercise. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-line to do all the task you need using `perl`

```
perl -pi -e 's/^(?!.*€)(.*)/\1€/g' inputFile
```

- `-p` process and print line by line
- `-i` for inplace replacement

If you only want to detect those lines using `grep` you can use `-P` option to for support of `Perl regex` and use `negative lookahead` like

```
grep -P '^(?!.*€)' inputFile
```